# Changing "will be" to "would have been" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> It will be foolish of him if he does not seize the opportunity.

My Approach:

> *It would have been foolish of him, if he hadn't seize the opportunity.*

or

> *It would have been foolish of him, if he not had seize the opportunity*.

I am confused in using these Sentence

### Which to use and why?

I want to make a sentence using an impossible conditional clause type - the
main clause should be in present perfect continuous and subordinate clause should be in past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

First off, we have to rewrite your 'base' present-tense sentence:

> It will be foolish of him if he does not seize the opportunity.

This sentence is only marginally idiomatic as it stands, and it will not bear casting into what you call "impossible" modality. It's not really a conditional at all: the "it" which is to be "foolish of him" is neither a logical nor a practical consequence of his failure to seize the opportunity, it **is** the failure itself. We would ordinarily express this with an infinitival rather than a conditional:

> It will be foolish of him not to seize the opportunity.

Moreover, the verb in the main (consequence) clause is a stative, so it cannot ordinarily be cast into the continuous construction.

So let's start by writing a true present-tense conditional with a continuous construction in the consequence clause:

> If he **thinks** we will help he **is deceiving** himself.

This may be cast into present-tense "impossible" modality like this:

> If he **thought** we would help, he **would be deceiving** himself.

And that may be cast into the past tense like this:

> If he **had thought** we would help, he **would have been deceiving** himself.

That's probably what you have in mind when you speak of a main clause in "present perfect continuous" and a condition clause in "past perfect". However, those are not accurate descriptions of the constructions in these sentences. The apparent perfects are actually past-tense markers. *He had thought* **looks** like a past perfect, but it is actually an irrealis ("impossible") past; and *he would have been deceiving* **looks like** a modal present perfect, but it's actual a modal past.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your approaches are correct. You tried to make the sentences in the past tense, which is not correct or possible.  I think what you mean is:

"He'd be foolish not to seize the/that opportunity"

Comment: NO i want to make a sentence using an impossible conditional clause type so i think the statement is right.

Comment: What about "It was foolish of him not to seize the opportunity."? Does that help?

Comment: main clause  should be in present perfect continuous and subordinate clause should be in past perfect

Comment: @JalajChawla - Those clarifications really, REALLY should have been in your original question. I've added them now. In the future, please take more care to clarify **exactly** what you are trying to ask; otherwise, you will probably get a lot of answers that aren't very helpful to you, and you will be wasting the community's valuable time.